# Missing iOS Xcode Templates

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm just starting coding with Xcode and am following a few examples. They show images of creating a new file and under the iOS section of the dialogue they contain "Cocoa Touch Class" and "User Interface". All I have under that section is "Resource" and "Appcelerator" (I installed Titanium).

Any idea why I am missing these template options and how I can get them installed?

Thanks,

David

Comment: What Version of XCode? I think Titanium is the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I've seen a bug report in their forums with someone with the same problem. I'm reinstalling the SDK to see if they get restored. Version is 3.2.6 if I remembered it correctly.

Comment: This just affected me, again. Pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nick suggested, it was Appcelerator Titanium that deleted the templates. Reinstalling the SDK restored them.

A link the appcelerator forums details the problem http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/68591/titanium-mobile-1411-deletes-xcodes-ios-file-templates

Comment: I've posted the fix to this in that appcelerator thread. Hopefully they include it in a release soon.